# Interaction of host and guest virtual machine

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

Does anyone know how to send the output of a Python script on my host machine to the guest virtual machine. I have a Python script on the guest VM that gets a value as an input from the script on host machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Copy/Paste between Host and Guest systems (Feature of VMWare), or if this is an ongoing connection between these two scripts you can use socket connections.

Answer (score 0):

If the machines have access to a shared network folder, you could create a filename in that folder with your python script, and read that filename from that folder from the guest.  After reading the filename, the guest could delete the file and that lets the host know that the input has been accepted.  This is very easy to set up if all you need is simple communications.  You can actually send the data via the filename itself, or inside a file, depending on the amount of data you need to send.